# PyCharm comment print lines

Tags: python, intellij-idea, replace, pycharm, comments

Is there any shortcut in the IntelliJ IDE such as PyCharm to comment all the lines start with `'print'`?

Since during the debug I always write many prints, after the code runs well I want to find a convenient way to comment on all lines starting with `'print'`. Now I select each `line/block` with command `+ /` which is trouble.

Comment: Maybe you need to debug in a different way. Yes, `print()` is nice in the small to see what your program sees and to see in what order things happen, but ultimately unit tests are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Well the unit test costs more time than print and it's not necessary in own quick experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about pycharm, but I guess you could use find/replace with a regex like `'^print'` and substitute with `'# print'`. Maybe you can even make this a macro / Hotkey in pycharm.

Comment: Thanks. It's a very clever way and quickly finished.

Comment: The '^print' only matches print with no indentations, '^[ \t]+print' match other 'indentation + print' with regrex. While even finding them out, in the replace box if you simple type '# print' it will break the original indentations. Any idea to solve this to keep the original indentations but insert the # between indentations and print?

Comment: Ah, you're right. Forgot about indentation. You can use capturing groups in regex and only substitute these groups. I don't know if this works with find/replace in pycharm though. You could use `'^[ \t]*(print)'`. It would match any print statement at the beginning of a line with and without indentation, but only have `print` in the capturing group `()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Find: (^[ \t]*)(print)
Replace: $1## $2
```

Comment: This one works great, really helpful if you are upgrading from python 2.7 to python 3 and you love to put prints everywhere

Comment: I would also recommend this over the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
Find: print(
Replace: #print(
```

And, to get back:

```
Find: #print(
Replace: print(
```

This worked pretty well for me. I don't find the reason for using complex regex for this.